# Check whether time-series 1 is greater than time-series 2 for a specific continuous duration

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have two time-series (`timeseries1`, `timeseries2`) of the same duration as

```
    library(xts)
    set.seed <- 1024
    series <- seq(from= as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")),to = as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-01-02", format="%Y-%m-%d")), by= "10 mins") 
    timeseries1 <- xts(rnorm(length(series),50,2),series)
    timeseries2 <- xts(rnorm(length(series),51.5,1),series)
    plot(timeseries1,main="")
    lines(timeseries2,col="blue")
    legend("topleft", legend=c("Timeseries-1","Timeseries-2"),lty = 1, col=c("black","blue"))
```

Plots is:
[image]

I need to find whether `timeseries2` is greater than `timeseries1` for a continuous duration of one hour. I know, I can start with point by point comparison and keep a counter to check whether `timeseries2` is greater than `timeseries1` for `n` intervals, but I think there must be some existing novel method for this.

Is there any existing method to do this for time-series data in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the rle function, which computes the length of runs of equal values.

In your case, you can check if timeseries2 is greater than timeseries1 for a continuous duration of one hour as follows:

```
comparison <- c(ifelse(coredata(timeseries2) > coredata(timeseries1),1,0))
lenghEnc <- rle(comparison)

any(lenghEnc$lengths>=6 & lenghEnc$values==1)
```